# Typeof === 'undefined' issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, undefined, typeof

Newbie here trying to work on this function which is supposed to console.log "I am undefined" if the contents of href is blank. I would appreciate any help as I am VERY stuck... :-(

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.facebook').each(function () {
        var facebook = $(this).attr('href')
        if (typeof facebook === "undefined") {
            console.log("I am undefined");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You facebook variable is null not undefined.Check for null not undefined.

Comment: check facebook using alert or console.log(facebook)

Answer (score 6):

It won't be undefined, I think you can probably use :-

```
if (!facebook) {
    console.log("I am undefined");
}
```

it will take care of any falsy value as `null`, `undefined`, `""`.

Answer (score 3):

`.attr` return plain object . it won't return undefined

Try like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.facebook').each(function () {
        var facebook = $(this).attr('href')
        if (!facebook) {
            console.log("I am undefined");
        }
    });
});
```